# c#: Serializing an object having interface as properties in readable format

Tags: c#, serialization

I searched, but couldn't find a satisfying answer. I know there are serializers like: DataContractJsonSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer to do that. But these required a weird requirement of specifying 'KnownType', which is not possible in my scenario as object i am serializing belongs to generic library, and actual implementations of interface could come from client.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

[ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) has a JSON serializer which doesn't require specifying the known types:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(myObj);
```

Or using extension methods you can call ToJson on any object:

```
var json = myObj.ToJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Json.Net` has a method `SerializeObject`. This would do the job for you.

It's signature is:

```
public static string SerializeObject(object value);
```

usage:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```